# CSS - Triggering a transition immediately after adding to DOM on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

If I add an element that I want to transition immediately after adding to the DOM, I have to do something like this for Chrome:

CSS:

```
div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
  var div = document.createElement("div")
  document.body.append(div);
  setTimeout(()=>div.classList.add("show"), 1);
```

A delay is necessary, otherwise a transition will not play, it will just immediately display the element with `opacity:1`

However, Firefox does not activate the transition with a 1ms delay.
If I set the timeout to 10ms, then there will be a transition about 50% of the time, it's a bit random.
Increasing it to 100ms ensures the transition will play, but that's too long.
I thought perhaps wrapping it in a requestAnimationFrame instead of a setTimeout would work but it doesn't.

How can I improve this without adding arbitrary delays?

Comment: _"Firefox does not activate the transition with a 1ms delay"_ - it does for me, at least with the basic example you have shown: https://jsfiddle.net/ey25mbwg/ - I can run that as many times as I like, I can not bring Firefox to _not_ show the div element, ever.

Comment: I tried your fiddle repeatedly and was surprised to see there was no issue. Then I altered it slightly for more vigorous testing and discovered that it was still a problem about 10% of the time. I setup a click listener to trigger a new element + animation, click fast and you may see it.
https://jsfiddle.net/udqt9L6w/

I think the more 'busy' a webpage is (as in the site I'm designing) the more this quirk is noticeable and longer delays are needed.
The fiddle being quite simple, requires a small delay on firefox to trigger the animation, but as I've proven 1ms is not enough sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`animate` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate).

```js
document.querySelector("#foo").animate([{opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1}], 200);
```

It's [supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_animate) in all major browsers.